# Not able to use Custom Field On Kanban view to group the records for Contact Object

Tags: lightning, kanban

While creating kanban view on Contact object, I could not see the custom field available for grouping. Is their a way we can bring it? Or it has the limitation?

Note:- Only standards fields are available to group it. Also, my custom fields are of type picklist.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Kanban](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=kanban_configuration.htm&type=5) views only support grouping by:
- Picklist
- Owner

Custom fields of other types will not show as a Group By option.

Lastly, your custom field must be on a Page Layout for it to show as a Group By option.

Comment: No, they are of type picklist

Comment: got it - add the field to Page Layout, then you will be able to select it as a filter.

Comment: Yes, It worked. Thanks